# PHP: Get unique sales and amounts

Tags: php

In a dummy database, I have a list of user ids and a list of product ids (belonging to items they have bought).

The data is like this:

```
1:54,3:54,3:88,7:234,4:344,1:54,76:12,1:54
```

> Represented: **UserID** : **ProductID**

From the above data you can see:

> User Id **1** has made 3 Sales
>
> User Id **3** has made 2 Sales
>
> User Id **7** has made 1 Sale
>
> User Id **4** has made 1 Sale
>
> User Id **76** has made 1 Sale

I am struggling to get the results so I can display them in a table:

```
User ID   |  # Sales
____________________

1            3
3            2
7            1
4            1
76           1
____________________

Unique Users (5)
Total Sales (8)
```

At the moment I have

```
$data = "1:54,3:54,3:88,7:234,4:344,1:54,76:12,1:54";
$data = explode(",", $data);

$result = array();
foreach ($data as $value) {
  $d_array = explode(":", $value);
   foreach ($d_array as $key => $value) {
    echo "<br/> Use: " .$key . "Item: ". $value; 
   }
}
```

What I am getting is:

```
User:0 Item: 1
User:1 Item: 54
User:0 Item: 3
User:1 Item: 54

/// etc...
```

## Question.

How Do I get the the unique amount of users, and the total sales?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$data = "1:54,3:54,3:88,7:234,4:344,1:54,76:12,1:54";
$data = explode(",", $data);

$result = array();
foreach ($data as $value) {
    $d_array = explode(":", $value);
    if(isset($result[$d_array[0]]))
        $result[$d_array[0]] +=1;
    else
        $result[$d_array[0]] = 1;
}
$user_unique = count($result);
$total = count($data);


var_dump($result);
var_dump($total);
var_dump($user_unique);
```

And the result

```
array (size=5)
 1 => int 3
 3 => int 2
 7 => int 1
 4 => int 1
 76 => int 1

int 8
int 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$data = "1:54,3:54,3:88,7:234,4:344,1:54,76:12,1:54";
$data = explode(",", $data);

$result = array();
foreach ($data as $value) {
  $d_array = explode(":", $value);
  if (count($d_array) == 2)
    echo "<br/> Use: " .$d_array[0] . "Item: ". $d_array[1]; 
}
```

Explode function is exploding a string into array items not into name-value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is to just count the users up as you are printing them.

Like this:

```
    $data = "1:54,3:54,3:88,7:234,4:344,1:54,76:12,1:54";
    $data = explode(",", $data);

    $totalSalesNr = = $totalSalesAmnt = 0;

    $result = $users = array();
    foreach ($data as $value) {
       $d_array = array();
       parse_str(str_replace(':', '=', $value), $d_array);
       foreach ($d_array as $key => $value) {
        $totalSalesNr++; $totalSalesAmnt += $value;
        if(!in_array($key, $users)) $users[] = $key;
        echo "<br/> User: " .$key . "Item: ". $value; 
       }
    }
echo "<br />Total Users: ". count($users) . " Total Sales: $totalSalesNr (Amount: $totalSalesAmnt)";
```

Comment: This returns total users 8. and sales 894 : / I want Total users: 5 and total sales 8 : /

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't noticed, that there are users are listed more than once :/ sorry for that. Hm ok then I will edit the answer ^^

Answer (score 0):

So you want to get

> the unique amount of users, and the total sales

then you can just do magic like this:

```
$string = "1:54,3:54,3:88,7:234,4:344,1:54,76:12,1:54";
$arr = explode(",", $string);
$users = 0;
$sales = 0;
foreach($arr as $pair)
{
   $pairarr = explode(":", $pair);
   $users += intval($pairarr[0]);
   $sales += intval($pairarr[1]);
}
echo "There are {$users} Users, which made a total amount of {$sales} Sales.";
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the ForEach Loop, we can achieve your requirement.

```
$data = "1:54,3:54,3:88,7:234,4:344,1:54,76:12,1:54";
$data = explode(",", $data);

$dataItem = array();

foreach ($dataItem as $item) {
    $uid = explode(":", $item);
    array_push($dataItem, $uid[0]);
}

foreach (array_unique($dataItem) as $item) {
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($dataItem as $subitem) {
        if($item == $subitem)
            $count++;
    }
    echo "<br/> User ID: " .$item . "Sales: ". $count; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking fo this answe,

this way you will get all the items every user has
the key on the result array will be the user, and the value will be the items every user has.

```
foreach ($data as $value) {
        $d_array = explode(":", $value);

            if (isset($result[trim($d_array[0])] ) ){
                $result[trim($d_array[0])] .= trim($d_array[1]) . ' | '; 
            }else{
                $result[trim($d_array[0])] ='Items: ' .$d_array[1] . ' | '; 
            }
        }
        print_r($result);
```

for the total sales, you can simply

```
    $data = '1:54,3:54,3:88,7:234,4:344,1:54,76:12,1:54'; 
    $data = explode(",", $data);
    $count = count($data); // total sales
    print_r($count) ;
```

Outputs

Sales

```
Array
(
    [1] => Items: 54 | 54 | 54 | 
    [3] => Items: 54 | 88 | 
    [7] => Items: 234
    [4] => Items: 344
    [76] => Items: 12
)
Total Sales
8
```

hope that helps